# Android SDK, Positioning items in view/Activity

Tags: android, sdk

I am normall used to a drag and position UI where the position of things are where you can place them on the screen and tidy things up using their properties X & Y postions, for instance on the iPhone/xCode.

No with android if you drag items on the screen they all snap to the top under each other etc depending what main layout option you choose.

But whats the best way to do this.

For example:
I have a textView and would like it 100px from the top and 20px from the left, then I have two buttons both 60px from the bottom and one 20px from the left and the other 20px form the right so they sit next to each other spaced out.

Now I now I use dp instead of px etc but these items do not seem to have x/y positions in the property and the only way I can position them is using margins or padding, is this correct or am Imissing something here? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should not be positioning stuff by pixels, as they are not guaranteed in shape, amount, etc etc. Better use something less device specific

Comment: Thanks for thi sbut as mentioned i used px as example as I knwo to use dp and sp for txt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Layout in Android is very different from iOS. The nature of Android being more open, means many different screen sizes and aspect ratios are possible. To deal with this and create flexible layouts that work well with different devices, there are a number of classes that Android provides to layout views. You might want to start with reading this document on [Common Layout Objects](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html).

Comment: thanks for the comment, thought as much, will have to persist and learn a new way thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position objects in your views by using x/y positions, you can do that with [Relative Layouts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) and then making use of layout_margin* and layout_align*.  The following layout will result in a TextView that is centered horizontally and with an 80 dip margin between itself and the bottom of the screen (assuming this is the only layout and view in your xml file).

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dip"
        android:text="hello"
    />
```

`</RelativeLayout>`

Comment: Thanks for this will give it ago, I noticed the Relative layout, but it wsa a bit tempramental in the visual / graphical view.